# QGIS C++ 3D Map Scene

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, 3d, c++, 3d-map

I want to use QGIS with c++ api like ArcGis runtime sdk. I tried to use Qgs3DMapScene class like

```
QgsAbstract3DEngine *m_window3DEngine;
Qgs3DMapSettings *m_mapSettings = new Qgs3DMapSettings;
m_window3DEngine = new QgsWindow3DEngine;
Qgs3DMapScene *m_3Dscene = new Qgs3DMapScene(*m_mapSettings, m_window3DEngine);
```

Qgs3DMapScene takes parameter as const `Qgs3DMapScene( const Qgs3DMapSettings &map, QgsAbstract3DEngine *engine );`

But since QgsAbstract3DEngine is an abstract class i can not create it. So documentation says to use `QgsWindow3DEngine` class which inherits from `QgsAbstract3DEngine class`. After using the `QgsWindow3DEngine` class as parameter for `Qgs3DMapScene` i get "no matching constructor error".

Is there a way to use this class or should i use a different class for 3d view?